# How to retrieve the API Gateway URI upon post

Tags: uri, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, api-gateway

I'm developing a system in a microservices architecture using java8 and Spring Cloud. I implemented a post rest controller that receives an object in json and then saves it in the database. The problem is; how do I get the URI containing the API Gateway of the just saved object so I can return it on the created responde body?

Like, when I use 
`URI uri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("/{id}").buildAndExpand(savedProfile.getId()).toUri();`
 I get `http://Boss.mshome.net:8081/profile/1` instead of `localhost:8765/nukr-profile-service/profile/1` which is the endpoint with the API Gateway's path.

What's the best practice to retrieve this URI?

Comment: Why do you need to return api gateway url at all? Isn't it known explicitly?

Comment: It is. The thing is, I wanted to load it from eureka naming server, in case it changed port or server. So I decided to go with the solution I posted as an answer here. This way, even if the Gateway's url changes, it will not be a problem, since I'm loading it from Eureka naming server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I came to a solution I just don't know if it's best practice or not.
My post method ended up being like:

```
@PostMapping("/profile")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> createProfile(@Valid @RequestBody Profile profile) {
        UriComponents requestComponents = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentRequest().path("").build();
        InstanceInfo gatewayService = this.eurekaClient.getNextServerFromEureka(NUKR_API_GATEWAY_SERVICE, false);
        Profile savedProfile = this.profileRepository.save(profile);

        String uriStr = requestComponents.getScheme() + "://" + gatewayService.getIPAddr() + ":" + gatewayService.getPort() + "/" + this.profileServiceName +
                requestComponents.getPath() + "/" + savedProfile.getId();

        return ResponseEntity.created(URI.create(uriStr)).build();
    }
```

Comment: I've accepted my own answer, since it worked. But I'm sure there may be a more elegant way to do it -maybe using a config server?-. So if you know a better way to do it, please answer and I'll consider and maybe accept your answer!